# Importing shapefile in MATLAB?

Tags: shapefile, line, error, import, matlab

I have digitized three rivers on Google Earth and converted into shapefile to use in MATLAB. I have checked the shapefiles in ArcGIS and they are working. But while opening in MATLAB, it shows the following errors:

> Unsupported shape type PolyLineZ (type code = 13).
>
> headerTypeCode = readHeaderTypeCode(shpFileId,callingFcn);

The code I am giving is below:

```
water = shaperead('rivers', 'UseGeoCoords', true);
geoshow( water , 'Facecolor', 'blue')
```

Comment: It would seem Matlab can't cope with 3D polyline shapefiles (which is what PolylineZ type represents). Convert the shapefile to 2D only, and if you need the elevation data, add it as an attribute, not actual geometry data

Comment: @U2ros yes....you were right..it solved the purpose...but the next problem is the area which i specified in my program and the area inbuilt in the matlab for Russia are not matching.....may be due to projection system problem...i have used Lambert projection system..Can you suggest me something..??

Comment: Which Lambert exact projection are you using, they may have different properties

Comment: @U2ros i am using Lambert Conformal conic projection. I searched in the net and somewhere i found this projection is used for Russia.

Comment: conformic means that the objects will retain the same angles when they are projected but not neccessarily the area size. Hence your differences in measured areas

Comment: @U2ros so which projection should i use so that my area matches with the area in the matlab??

Comment: Check out this link: http://chatt.hdsb.ca/~vanelliss/FOV1-000B9892/FOV1-000B9932/FOV1-001056C1/?OpenItemURL=S09FACED4 Your are looking for an equal-area type of projection. There are no concrete projections listed there, but when you choose a type you should find one in the list of available SRSs

Answer (score 2):

In ArcGIS, use the tool Copy Features

select "Environment", then select Z Values, "disabled"

Do the same with M Values to be sure. The resulting shape file should open in Matlab.

[image]